Intellij disable intellisense for a block of code
I have Scala code that calls Java code, and intellij erroneously reports an error. (The code compiles and runs but Intellij highlights it in red).
(See the "setAuth" method call in the screenshot.)
Is there a way to disable intellisense for this particular block of code somehow?

